# Google Contacts API get phone number (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-contacts-api

I'm using the [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) and I'm able to extract names and email addresses but I'd like to also get profile pictures and phone numbers.

I'm using PHP and here's my code while authenticating:

```
//if authenticated successfully...

$req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
$val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->loadXML($val->getResponseBody());

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');

$emails = $xpath->query('//gd:email');

foreach ( $emails as $email ){

  echo $email->getAttribute('address'); //successfully gets person's email address

  echo $email->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent; //successfully gets person's name

}
```

**PHONE NUMBER**

This part getting the phone number **doesn't** work.

```
$phone = $xpath->query('//gd:phoneNumber');

foreach ( $phone as $row ){

  print_r($row); // THIS PART DOESNT WORK

}
```

**PROFILE PICTURE**

Judging from the API link above, it looks like I can also grab the profile picture from the URL: `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full` but I'm not sure how to find it within the `DOMXPath` `$xpath` object I generated.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Contacts API uses an Atom feed. The contacts are provided as `entry` elements. So it makes more sense the iterate them. To do that you have to register a prefix for the atom namespace as well.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$xpath->registerNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
```

If you use DOMXpath::evaluate() you can use expressions that return scalars. The second argument is a context node for the expression.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/atom:feed/atom:entry') as $entry) {
  $contact = [
    'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:title)', $entry),
    'image' => $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:link[@rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo"]/@href)', $entry),
    'emails' => [],
    'numbers' => []
  ];
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('gd:email', $entry) as $email) {
    $contact['emails'][] = $email->getAttribute('address');
  }
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('gd:phoneNumber', $entry) as $number) {
    $contact['numbers'][] = trim($number->textContent);
  }
  var_dump($contact);
}
```

With the first example response from the [Google Contacts API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) this returns:

```
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(17) "Fitzwilliam Darcy"
  ["image"]=>
  string(64) "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/userEmail/contactId"
  ["email"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["numbers"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "456"
  }
}
```

The example does not include an `email` element, so it is empty. A contact can have multiple email addresses and/or phone numbers or none at all. The `rel` attribute is provided to classify them as home, work, ...

### Fetching the image:

The image is provided as an Atom `link` element with a specific `rel` attribute.

`atom:link[@rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo"]`

This would return the `link` node, but it is possible to fetch the href attribute directly:

`atom:link[@rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo"]/@href`

Cast the attribute node list into a string:

`string(atom:link[@rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo"]/@href)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can confirm that the name and email part work well. The image is still giving me problems regardless of whether or not I append the `access token` to the result like this: `'image' => $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:link[@rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo"]/@href)', $entry). '&access_token='.urlencode($accesstoken)` Might you help?

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly you have to use the `Google_HttpRequest` object to send an authorized GET request to the image url to fetch it. Just like you fetch the XML feed but store/deliver the response as binary image data. Does my sample read valid looking image urls from the XML feed?